# How to retain the colors filled in ArcGIS map while applying custom rendering of increasing boundary width

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: AGSMapView!
private var map:AGSMap!
private var featureLayer:AGSFeatureLayer!

func loadAirQuality()
{
        if self.featureLayer == nil 
        {
            //create feature table using a url
            self.featureTable = AGSServiceFeatureTable(url: URL(string: hourlyMapURL)!)
            //create feature layer using this feature table
            self.featureLayer = AGSFeatureLayer(featureTable: self.featureTable)
            //create feature table using a url. This is the CSV table hosted on ESRI Online
            //self.zipSRACityTable = AGSServiceFeatureTable(url: URL(string: self.zipSRACityURL)!)
            self.featureLayer.labelsEnabled = false
            // set opacity of SRA regions
            self.featureLayer.opacity = Constant.mapOpacity
            self.mapView.graphicsOverlays.add(graphicsOverlay)
        }

        //add feature layer to the map
        self.map.operationalLayers.add(self.featureLayer)

        //add graphics overlay to the map view

        self.mapView.locationDisplay.autoPanMode = 
        AGSLocationDisplayAutoPanMode.recenter
}
```

Above is the default code being used and ArcGIS map fills color based on dataset recieved from feature layer. Is there any way of retaining the feature layer color with boundary width increased.
But if we try to increase the width of boundary using below code, then color disappears from map.

```
let lineSymbol = AGSSimpleLineSymbol(style: .solid, color: UIColor.black, width: 1)

    self.featureLayer.renderer = AGSSimpleRenderer(symbol: lineSymbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this code.

```
 // Create a outline symbol
        let outlineSymbol = AGSSimpleLineSymbol(style: .solid, color: .green, width: 2)

        // Create a fill symbol for polygon graphic
        let fillSymbol = AGSSimpleFillSymbol(style: .forwardDiagonal, color: .green, outline: outlineSymbol)
```

Comment: In this case it will remove other default colors which we recieve in data source. It will show the whole map with green color.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Would you upload a screenshot?